# Extrude an arc in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to extrude an arc using Three.js.
If I use the shape.arc(), it will create a full wedge or pie section.  I'd like to create a hollow pie, or just an extrusion of the edge of the pie.

Answer (score 0):

THREE doesn't offer much in terms of 2D shapes so you have to get the arc somehow.

If you don't need to generate it procedurally, you can draw the arc in illustrator as an enclosed shape, save it out as an SVG, use TWO.js (https://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/) to convert it into points, and then you can extract the points into THREE.js.

Another way is to use a library like clipper.js (http://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home%206/) to take your arc path, then expand it using its Offset feature to bloat out the path, then bring the vertices back into THREE